# Unable to create an [After UPDATE] trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a trigger that runs every time an update takes place.

Basically: I have two tables: `plans` that contains the master/header rows, and `plan_courses` that contain the details. `plans` has and `id` primary key, and `plan_courses` has a `plan_id` as foreign key.

Once a course is `attended`, I am supposed to count all courses within a plan and check if the attended count equal that total number of courses in a given plan. If so, then the whole header/master row should be marked as `done`. Otherwise, it shall be marked as `not done`.

Here is what I tried:

```
create trigger my_trigger on plan_courses 
after update 
as
begin

  declare @attended_cnt int;
  declare @total_cnt int;
  declare @plan_status varchar;

  select @total_cnt = count(*) from plan_courses where plan_id=inserted.plan_id;

  select @attended_cnt=count(*) from plan_courses 
         where plan_id=inserted.plan_id and course_status='attended';

  select @plan_status = case when @attended_cnt < @total_cnt then 'not done' else 'done' end;


  update plans set plan_status = @plan_status where id=inserted.plan_id;


end;
```

When I execute this, I get:

> SQL Server Database Error: The multi-part identifier "inserted.plan_id" could not be bound.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4024/sql-server-trigger-after-update-for-a-specific-value/) you can find a few tips on what's wrong with your trigger.

`INSERTED` is a reference to the `UPDATED` row, but in form of a table (If you want to call it like that).

What you should do to fix your queries is joining your table with the `INSERTED` in order to achieve your results:

```
create trigger my_trigger on plan_courses 
after update 
as
begin

  declare @attended_cnt int;
  declare @total_cnt int;
  declare @plan_status varchar;

  select @total_cnt = count(*) 
  from plan_courses as p
  inner join inserted as j
    on p.plan_id=j.plan_id;

  select @attended_cnt=count(*) 
  from plan_courses as p
  inner join inserted as j
    on p.plan_id = j.plan_id and p.course_status = 'attended';

  select @plan_status = case when @attended_cnt < @total_cnt then 'not done' else 'done' end;


  update plans 
  set plan_status = @plan_status 
  from plans as p
  inner join inserted as i
    on i.plan_id = p.id;


end;
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERTED` is a temp table here.

`select @total_cnt = count(*) from INSERTED`

[msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables)

Comment: isn't `INSERTED` a reference to the `UPDATED` row?

Comment: `select @total_cnt = count(*) from INSERTED` will always return 1 since I am updating a single row at a time. I don't know how this would help me. I have read the msdn documentation and could not find what is wrong with my code

Comment: Same thing - no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

you should join the tables and use `inserted` tables and not like below

`plan_id=inserted.plan_id`

you should do like below

```
 select @attended_cnt=count(*) from plan_courses p
                      join
                      inserted i on p.plan_id=i.plan_id and course_status='attended';
```

Comment: how about the final `update` before the `end`? how can I update the master table based on the `inserted` row?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, you can use inserted table join just like normal table ,,example `update p
set p.plan_status = i.plan_id
from plantable p
join inserted i 
on p.plan_id=i.plan_id;`